# " % if user.signature " - Statement remains in template

Tags: odoo-11

I am attempting to create an email template in Odoo 11 for Purchase order and RFQ.

My code is like so, which is copied from another template..

```
 % if user.signature

 ${user.signature | safe}

 % endif
```

When I create a new Email, the result is like this.

```
% if user.signature
--
Administrator

% endif
```

I have tried with the `:` syntax but all i get is a blank template.

I have tried without the `if` statement and it works as long as there is a signature..

```
 ${user.signature | safe}
```

How can I only display the Signature and not the `if` statements..

Do I need the if statements??

Answer (score 0):

You have forgotten ':' from syntax

```
% if user.signature : ${user.signature | safe}
 % endif
```

Try this one.

Comment: Apologies but I already tried with the `:` and it renders a completely blank template!!

Comment: Can you post your whole code? I think by this way that can be achieve. Seems there is something else affecting here.